# How to communicate between Python and other languages?

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, pipe, communication

I want to make a small application with graphical interface with Python but I want to do the calculations in another language such as C++ or Golang, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Build a .dll or .so file from your C++ source, then use [Python's `ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to import the functions from it. Alternatively, use the Python C API to create an extension module. The difference is that in the first approach, the interop code will be in Python, and in the second, it will be in your native code.